# R equivalent of Max windows function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to calculate the maximum value for a column so far in the dataset

The SQL equivalent would be something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(Sepal.length) over (PARTITION BY Species 
           ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and current row) as max_so_far
```

This is my code

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(
    flower_id = row_number()
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

I'd like to get the max Sepal length for any flower with the same flower id or a smaller flower ID in that species

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `cummax` :

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(
    flower_id = row_number()
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(running_max = cummax(Sepal.Length))
```